# Trouble with mat type conversion and accessing individual pixel

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I got a trouble when programming with OpenCV.
After a lot of time, I find out that, the result of cout << mat and individual pixel value are different after type conversion.

This is the code

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
Mat a = (Mat_<int>(3, 3) << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
cout << "Initial mat type: " << a.type() << endl;
cout << "Pos(1, 1): " << a.at<int>(1, 1) << endl;

a.convertTo(a, CV_8U);
cout << "CV_8U converted mat type: " << a.type() << endl;
cout << "Mat content: \n" << a << endl;
cout << "Pos(1, 1): " << a.at<int>(1, 1) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

And result here:

```
Initial mat type: 4 // CV_32S 
Pos(1, 1): 5
CV_8U converted mat type: 0 // CV_8U
Mat content: 
[1, 2, 3;
  4, 5, 6;
  7, 8, 9]
Pos(1, 1): -1254749944
```

That means, after converting from CV_32S to CV_8U, I get the right matrix from cout << a, but when accessing individual pixel, I got mess :|
Can you help me? thank !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've converted the values to a different type, you need to access them using a different type:

```
cout << "Pos(1, 1): " << static_cast<int>(a.at<uchar>(1, 1)) << endl;
```

Comment: When using `cout` you might want to add an explicit cast to int. `cout   << char(5)` might not provide the expected result

Comment: cout << "Pos(1, 1): " << (int)a.at<uchar>(1, 1) << endl; That's OK, thank you. I think I've figured problem, why the result of cout << a (print out a mat), and value of individual element are different. Is this because cout << a_mat is printing the character, not the integer or something numeric ?